# How to make button for Dark Mode

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I want to make possibility to switching between dark and light mode on my main screen. I don't want to make it with UISlider, but with just a button. You tap once and its dark mode, you tap again and its light. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Are you using UIKit or SwiftUi?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UIKit

###### UPDATE

The updated version is more reliable, it checks the overrideUserInterfaceStyle and if it is `.unspecified` there is a fallback to `UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle`

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ToggleInterfaceStyle
//
//  Created by Sebastian on 23.09.22.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Here is the button
        let toggleInterfaceStyleButton = UIButton()
        toggleInterfaceStyleButton.setTitle("Toggle Color Scheme", for: .normal)
        toggleInterfaceStyleButton.setTitleColor(.tintColor, for: .normal)
        toggleInterfaceStyleButton.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: -50, width: 250, height: 500)
        toggleInterfaceStyleButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggleInterfaceStyle), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(toggleInterfaceStyleButton)
    }
    
    
    @objc func toggleInterfaceStyle() {
        let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
        let window = windowScene?.windows.first
        let interfaceStyle = window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle == .unspecified ? UIScreen.main.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle : window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle
        
        if interfaceStyle != .dark {
            window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
        } else {
            window?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
        }
    }
}
```

[image: UIKit Toggle: User Interface Style (light/dark)]

### SwiftUI

For SwiftUI, you can change the appearance (light mode / dark mode) with `.preferredColorScheme`, it changes the appearance for the entire app. In this example I added a second view and a navigationLink to show that the styles stays as selected:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var scheme: ColorScheme = .light
    @State private var isShowingNewAccountView = false
    
    func toggleScheme() {
        if scheme == .light {
            scheme = .dark
        } else {
            scheme = .light
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView() {
            VStack {
                
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    .padding()
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .padding()
                
                
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
                    Text("Second View")
                }
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.toggleScheme()
                }) {
                    Text("Toggle Scheme")
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(scheme)
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Image(systemName: "airplane")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                .padding()
            Text("Hello, second view!")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: SwiftUI Toggle: User Interface Style (light/dark)]

Comment: I think this is UIKit and not SwiftUI. At least "UISlider" hints toward that.

Comment: You are right, I am sorry, I missed that.

Comment: Thanks! @SebastianFox. But i wrote my question incorrectly. This button should change light/dark style for every screen, not only for main, i have 4 VC in total. How to do it? I guess its something in objc func?

Comment: Hi @Sirius, I updated the UIKit portion. Now it should change the style within the entire app. Instead of the the style of the current view, it now changes the style of the window. In my test code it worked well (it is not seen in the gif, it is still the old gif) .